# Generic mapper using Typescript

Tags: typescript

The use case here is for instance mapping a fetch response with a json result into a more complex class using generics.

For instance `mapper<T,U>(U json)` where `T` is the expected return Type. And `U` is optionally the json class.

`U` could be an array e.g. resulting in `T[]` or `Array<T>` being mapped out.

For instance given a `User`:

```js
interface CustomAdressImplementation {
  street: string;
  streetNumber: string;
  city: string;
  zip: string;
}

interface User {
  id: string;
  birthDate: Date;
  name: string;
  address: CustomAdressImplementation;
}
```

example json `UserJson`:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "birthdate": "2020-02-20T10:00:19.145Z"
    "name": "Leanne Graham"
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "streetNo": "2b"
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
  },
  [... more users] 
]
```

One way of custom mapping this is just by creating a mapper method:

```js
interface GeoJson {
  lat: string;
  lng: string;
}

interface AddressJson {
  street: string;
  streetNo: string;
  suite: string;
  city: string;
  zipcode: string;
  geo: GeoJson;
}

interface UserJson {
  id: number;
  birthdate: string;
  name: string;
  address: AddressJson;
}

export function mapAddress(json: AddressJson): CustomAdressImplementation {
  return {
    street: json.street,
    streetNumber: json.streetNo,
    city: json.city,
    zip: json.zipcode,
  };
}

export function mapUser(json: UserJson): User {
  return {
    id: json.id.toString(),
    birthDate: new Date(json.birthdate),
    name: json.name,
    address: mapAddress(json.address),
  };
}

export function mapUserList(json: UserJson[]): User[] {
  if (json) return json.map(mapUser);
  return [];
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of creating a ruleset for mapping this using generics? Or is manual custom mapping the way to go in typescript trading of complex mapping logic.

In my example Date, string conversion and mapping to the address class seems like it could be written more elegantly avoiding the boilerplate custom mapper method.

Using the class-transformer library is not an accepted solution, looking for a pure Typescript implementation using generics.

Comment: Consider modifying the code in the question to constitute a [mcve] without references to undeclared types or values, so that someone can drop it into a standalone IDE and make suggestions.  Right now, the types `CustomAdressImplementation` and `UserJson` are not defined and neither is the function `mapAddress`.  It would be easier to refactor the code into a more generic version if the current version were complete.

Comment: It would also help if you included an example of how you expect the generic version to be used.  The type system is erased when compiling to JS and the language doesn't let you create runtime code based on interface definitions, so any code you want to see running at runtime needs to be written by you (or a library, which you don't want).  I can imagine writing code to compose existing mappers to make more complex mappers, but I don't know if that's what you want without a more explicit sketch of what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm thinking of something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vhoqg1) but I can't tell if that's what you're looking for.  Can you check it out and comment?

Comment: @jcalz I edited the answer and added an assumption. I am previously from the .Net world and Automapper is a good example of what I am looking for. And I want the interface to be generics. I clearly understand how typescript works in the sense that the code is converted into js.

Comment: I will see if I can add a full minimal reproducible example, thank you

Comment: Whether "the code is converted into js" depends strongly on what you mean by "converted".  The TypeScript code `interface Foo { a: string; b: number }` compiles to completely empty JavaScript, so at runtime there's nothing called `Foo` at all.  The code `class Bar { a: string; b: number }` is often compiled to something like `class Bar { }`, so while there is a `Bar` constructor, there's no runtime knowledge of the keys and values of the properties.  This makes it difficult to imagine writing a pure-TS solution that doesn't do more work than you are possibly envisioning.

Comment: I still don't see an [mcve] in there; I guess you can't get to it.  Please review my suggested approach [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vhoqg1) and tell me what you think; you'd be defining your classes based on your conversion schemas instead of vice versa.

Comment: I am not looking into continue this thread, on discussing Typescript transpilation or semtantics around explaining this, I clearly got that understanding, thank you. 

Thank you for your tips on creating a minimal reproducible example, I did not get around to edit it.


I will check your suggested approach and give feedback on it, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AutoMapper TypeScript](https://automapperts.netlify.app/) is a tool that provides object-object mapping by convention and it follows as close as possible to the original .NET AutoMapper.

The example [here](https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/getting-started/introduce-to-automapper) is quite similar to the problem description and also provides a solution.

Comment: Automapper from netlify does not work in nestjs with sequelize entities. Author can't help. Worked with older version of sequelize.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `mapList` function that inference the passed mapper:

```
// Some UserJson type
type UserJson = {
  [key: string]: any;
};

// User type
type User = {
  id: string;
  birthDate: Date;
  name: string;
  orderLines: any;
};

// All mappers should receive a json of type T and return a type U
interface Mapper<T, U> {
  (json: T): U;
}

// We declare the mapper of user, should receive a UserJson (T) and returns an User (U)
type mapUser = Mapper<UserJson, User>;

function mapUser(json: UserJson): User {
  return {
    id: json.id.toString(),
    birthDate: new Date(json.birthdate),
    name: json.name,
    orderLines: json.address
  };
}

// mapList receives a Mapper<T, U> and returns a function with type (json: T[]) => U[]
function mapList<T, U>(mapper: Mapper<T, U>): (json: T[]) => U[] {
  return (json: T[]): U[] => {
    if (json) return json.map(mapper);
    return [];
  };
}

// As mapList received a Mapper<UserJson, User>, it will return (json: UserJson[]) => User[]
const mapUserList = mapList(mapUser);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-darkness-3m7j5?file=/src/index.ts:0-690)